# Can I change a Mov file of one Codec type to a Mov file of another Codec type

Tags: video, quicktime, file-conversion, open-source

I have a lot of MOV files that are "Codec: Timecode, AAC, Apple ProRes 444" and "Color profile: SD(6-1-6)" and I want to change them to "Codecs: H.264, AAC" and "Colour profile: HD (1-1-1)" but I can't find a combination of switches in ffmpeg to do it. 
So basically I want to change a folder with a list of mov files in it from one Codec & Colour profile to another.
Is there a way of doing this?